# Best way to authenticate via OAuth in WinRT Windows Store App

Tags: c#, oauth, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, portable-class-library

Anybody knows about any tools which I could use to authenticate via OAuth in my Windows Store application written in c# XAML approach?

I known about DotNetOpenAuth, and Hammock but these tools are not PCL, and I can not reference it from my app!

Only way is to manualy generate requests and send it via `HttpClient`? Or, is any simpler way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  When selecting tags, please be sure to read the tag summary to make sure you're picking the correct thing.  Windows RT is not the same thing as WinRT, and the PCL tag is for the printer language, not the Portable Class Library.

Comment: I used restsharp http://restsharp.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is late response, but maybe I will help some one.

From what I remember I used ultimately [restsharp](http://restsharp.org/), It done job very well.

Comment: RestSharp is not compatible with WinRT.

Answer (score 0):

You would use WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync to authenticate via OAuth against OAuth providing websites like Twitter, Facebook a.s.o.

See the Microsoft [Web authentication broker sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this sample is not completed solution for authentication process via OAuth 1.0. More over this sample did not show how to comunicate with REST service.

Comment: I meant about building appropriate message to comunicate with REST service. I still do not known if some tool exist, which I can use to easy communication with REST service (with OAuth 1.0 auth). But, I implemented it myself, using HttpClient... Dev pages on twitter are very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I have just found this OAuth library for PCL (Portable Class Libraries).

[Source Code](https://github.com/neuecc/AsyncOAuth):

[Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncOAuth/)

I have not tested it.

Comment: Hmm, when I try to install it I get this: Install-Package : Unable to find package 'AsyncOAuth'.