# Windows Store app proxy issue

Tags: windows-8

i'm trying to get some data from internet using following code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

string URL = "http://server/test/userauth?operation=loginAuth&userName=" + 
strEncryptedUsername   + "&password=" + strEncryptedPassword 

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(URL);

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Getting proxy "407 authorization required" error. Please help. This is a windows store app.

Comment: Windows Store App, but `deviceOS=iOS` ?

Comment: Please ignore the url paranmeters. It was done for executing a piece of code on server.

Answer (score 0):

Try these it may help you

[Basic HTTP Authentication in WinRT](http://massivescale.com/pages/basic-http-authentication-in-winrt/)

[HttpClient Basic Authentication for WinRT](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/httpclient-basic-authentication-winrt/)

[Best way to authenticate via OAuth in WinRT Windows Store App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458949/best-way-to-authenticate-via-oauth-in-winrt-windows-store-app)

Comment: resolved using the HttpWebRequest object and setting its proxy property